# Is the relation $xRy$ iff $|x - y| \leq 2$ transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Question: $xRy$ iff $|x-y| \leq 2$

I think I've found this to be reflexive and symmetric, but I'm stuck on transitivity. Can someone assist me with testing transitivity?

Comment: It is not transitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, $|2-4|\le2$ and $|4-6|\le2$ but you don't have $|2-6|\le2$. So it is not transitive.

Comment: thanks but i wanted to know if its also antisymmetric?

Comment: @jason $1 R 2$ and $2 R 1$. (In fact $R$ is symmetric, but not the identity relation.) What does this tell you about antisymmetry of $R$?

Comment: yes i know that antisymmetric is when 1=2 but i wanted to confirm

Comment: @jason Right, it isn't.